# cURL error 5: Could not resolve proxy when using proxy request in PHP Laravel with Guzzle

Tags: php, laravel, curl, proxy, guzzle

I have a function that checks if a proxy is working using Guzzle. The code is as follows:

```
private function isValidProxy($ip, $port, $username, $password)
    {
        // Construct proxy URL with authentication if username and password are provided
        $proxyUrl = "http://$ip:$port";
        if ($username && $password) {
            $proxyUrl = sprintf(
                'http://%s:%s@%s',
                urlencode($username),
                urlencode($password),
                $proxyUrl
            );
        }

        // Make a request using Guzzle
        try {
            $client = new Client([
                'base_uri' => 'https://google.com',
                'proxy' => $proxyUrl,
                'timeout' => 5,
            ]);

            // Make a request to a specific test endpoint on the target website
            $response = $client->get('/');

            // Check if the response indicates success
            return $response->getStatusCode() === 200;
        } catch (RequestException $e) {
            return $e;
            // Proxy is not functional
            return false;
        }
    }
```

When I test it with a public proxy without a username and password, it works fine. However, when I use a private proxy with authentication (username and password), I get the cURL error 5: Could not resolve proxy.

I've verified that the private proxy details are correct, and I'm not sure why I'm encountering this issue. Could someone help me understand what might be causing this error and suggest a solution?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure, but when you want to connect to a proxy, you should use HTTPS as a secure protocol.
try to replace **http://** by **https://** everywhere in your code.

Actually, try to remove the 'http://' part when you compose the ip with its port, indeed, you should put  it directly since the prefix is already set in first. It's totally normal that you couldn't resolve the site name, by doing this, it should work.

Comment: I have tried switching to 'https://' in the proxy URL, but unfortunately, it didn't resolve the error

Comment: try now to delete http:// from variable $proxyUrl, it's the origin of your problem, since the url format should be like  http://<user>:<password>@<domain or IP address>:<port> and not  like http://<user>:<password>@http://<domain or IP address>:<port>